# Actions Must be plain objects. Use Custom middleware for async actions when I already have thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have thunk middleware applied but I am still getting impure error. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Where I call the creator

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import { shallowEqual, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { signIn } from '../../redux/actions/user'

const LogInOrSignUpScreen = () => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user, shallowEqual)

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login Or Sign up</Text>
      <Button title='clicked' onPress={useDispatch(signIn('ok', 'dal'))} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default LogInOrSignUpScreen
```

Reducer

```js
export const userReducer = (state = { ...initState.user }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_IN_ERROR:
      return state;
    // case SIGN_IN_PENDING:
    //     return state;
    case SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, ...action.data }
    default:
      //console.log(state)
      return state;
  }
}
```

Async Action Creator:

```js
export function signIn(userId, pass) {
  let creditials = { userId, pass }
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(signInPending())
    try {
      console.log('clicked')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      dispatch(signInError());
      // return;
    }
    dispatch(signInSuccess(creditials))
  }
}
```

Configure Store

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import { initialState } from './dataModel'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

export function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
  )
}

export default configureStore;
```

App.js

```js
const store = configureStore()

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isUserLoggedIn()}
    </NavigationContainer>
  </Provider>
)
```

The text below is the fulfill the requirement of me having more filler info about the question I do apologize.

I have thunk middleware applied but I am still getting impure error. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

I was just using the raw useDispatch function... instead of storing the instance in a variable.....

thanks for looking over my problem and I hope this helps someone else as well.